# properties that can't be copied to new location onedrive photos

Tags: onedrive

Ok so the title is only half the story, the issue is I have a few files on my very old desktop which I needed to recover. I had backed up all my files using SkyDrive (which is now OneDrive) and it was all there after an update and some files deleting I lost everything. Recently I found a folder under my User/SkyDrive folder which contained everything, which was like a jackpot for me because after deleting them I realized I needed them later on. Anyway I looked at some of the images but all of them were about 24KB~ and looked like a stretched thumbnail when opened.

What is interesting though the "Actual Size" was over 1MB~ but size on disk was 24-28KB~ Anyway when I tried to copy the files from the folder into a thumb drive it started giving me the "properties cannot be copied to new location" error. I was wondering is there any way to recover these photos and files? They seem to have an actual size and size on disk which is really confusing me at the moment.

It would be awesome if someone could even explain it to me. Thanks!

EDIT: I have formatted thumb drive to NTFS just in case anyone is wondering about the NTFS storing data in "streams" and cannot transfer it to FAT based file systems. But after copying those files it still doesn't open.